# postgres full text search for a query that has JOINS, what techniques are there to solve this type of query?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I want to add full-text search for the below query, this query has joins also:

```
select p.id, p.sku, p.name, ..., l.name, m.name
from products p
    join locations l on l.id = p.id
    join manufactures m on m.id = p.id
where ...
```

I am creating a column that will have a concatenation of the columns that I need to index:

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD COLUMN products_ts tsvector
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(col1, '') || ' ' coalesce(col2, '') )) STORED;
```

I create a GIN index on the above column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_products_search_ts ON products USING GIN(products_ts);
```

I have a table that I need to search across 15 columns, the columns are either text or numerical (like order numbers).

```
john doe
11223344
```

My query requires an JOIN to the locations and manufactures table, and I want people to be able to search
based on the product attributes and also the location name or manufacturer name.

What techniques/strategies are there to somehow full-text index columns that are in a JOIN table?

Will the above index handle both text search and numerical searches?
e.g. someone searches for order # 100039393, will it perform partial matches on that order number also?

Comment: My understanding of a join table is a table whose only columns are ids into other tables.  You don't seem to have one of those.  And your question about searching on numbers seems unrelated to there being joins.

Comment: You can search on 3 columns, or you can create a new ts_vector column containing all the information and that is updated by trigger on any change in the 3 related tables (that is, the trigger joins the 3 tables, concatenates the information and updates the resulting ts_vector)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in another comment, creating a trigger that fills a ts column with data from the joined tables is probably the best solution. I created a small example in this sql-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cvYHnv6RNgvZNsSfqEtkjf/10 (ts_data column left as text for simplicity)

It should be easy enough to expand this to include data from manufactures table.